# Foreign key issues with Apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apartment-gem

Getting the below error with associated (belongs_to) models:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "employees" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_0d62068e18" DETAIL: Key (contract_type_id)=(2) is not present in table "contract_types". : INSERT INTO "employees" ("title_id", "surname", "othernames", "department_id", "job_title_id", "gender_id", "date_of_birth", "contract_type_id", "employee_status_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"
```

In this case, `contract_type_id` is a foreign_key to an excluded model (ContractType)

The error is reported to have come from this line:

```
@connection.exec_prepared(stmt_key, type_casted_binds.map { |_, val| val })
```

I am using postgres with the `config.use_schemas = true` option.

Comment: Do you have a ContractType with an id equal to `2`? It seems that your SQL query is trying to create a relationship between an Employee and a non-existing ContractType (try `ContractType.find(2)` in your console to check if the record exists)

Comment: Yeah, I have a record with that id but that model is part of the excluded ones.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your model relationships correctly, [this may help readers understand the problem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/248).  The short: Apartment does not support foreign key constraints between non-excluded models to excluded models.