# Foreign key issue with apartment gem is there any other solution to insert data in associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, apartment-gem

Following is the error I get when I add data in the associated model from the master database.

> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: 
>    insert or update on table "configurations" violates foreign key
>    constraint "fk_rails_29e23e6ceb" DETAIL:  Key (company_id)=(129) is
>    not present in table "companies".

Comment: share you model schemas..

Comment: Company
has_many :configurations

Configuration
belongs_to :company

``` Company model is excluded from tenant, And Configuration model are in tenent```

Comment: `schema` as in table columns and datatypes and not `associations`..

Comment: **  
create_table "configurations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "key"
    t.string   "value"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.integer  "catelog_source_id"
    t.boolean  "visible",           default: true
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.index ["catelog_source_id"], name: 
   "index_configurations_on_catelog_source_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_configurations_on_company_id", 
    using: :btree
  end

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36141248/59991) seems to indicate it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent a lot of time trying to figure what caused this.
The solution is quite simple (at least in my case).
Straight from the documentation of the gem:

> If you have some models that should always access the 'public' tenant,
>   you can specify this by configuring Apartment using
>   Apartment.configure. This will yield a config object for you. You can> 
>   set excluded models like so:
>
> ````
> config.excluded_models = ["User", "Company"]        # these models
>  will not be multi-tenanted, but remain in the global (public)
>  namespace  ```
> ````

So just add it your apartment.rb file.

```
Apartment.configure do |config|
  config.excluded_models = %w{ User Company }
  ...
end
```